# What children's TV show had a boy recruited by an organisation because he was the best at a computer game?

Tags: story-identification, tv

It was about this boy who was the best player of a computer game in the world, and gets recruited by this organisation by using the same weapons in the game.

It was a drama played by actors, not a cartoon. Anyone know the title of it?

Comment: I don't know about cartoon, but the movie "The Last Starfighter" is that exact plot. It was also turned into a video game, but not a cartoon.

Comment: You need to add some additional details.  When did you view it ?  How about a bit more of the plot line.  And do check out [The Last Starfighter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_Starfighter). @JohnP - you might want to add as possible answer before someone else does.

Comment: I wonder if this could be Captain Power. It had real life toys that interacted with included video tapes.

Comment: sounds like Aron Stone

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/194746/what-vintage-movie-had-this-blue-floating-holographic-head-talking-to-some-kind (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 23):

The Last Starfighter (1984) is a feature length theatrical release that fits the main plot elements you have outlined here.

Main protagonist is named Alex Rogan, who's kind of an average teenager, who does maintenance at a trailer park and is the best at the video game Starfighter.

> Unknown to Alex, the video game is actually a test, and the conditions in the game with
>  the war against "Xur and the Ko-Dan armada" are real.

After much teen angst, Alex

> Gets his act together and saves Rylos, and is proclaimed a hero by the people. He returns 
>  to Earth to get his girlfriend and then leaves to train a new generation of Starfighters.

Answer (score 6):

You might be thinking of the first episode of Stargate Universe, where character Eli Wallace is playing a game called Prometheus. Being the first and only person to <strike>win the game</strike> solve a top secret weapon puzzle placed in the game results in the military general in charge of the Stargate program showing up at his door...

Comment: He figures out a math puzzle, there was no hint of how good at the game he was otherwise, it's not a children's show, and no weapons were involved

Comment: I think it was implied he was very good at the game, and the answer is not supposed to be a children's show (necessarily).

Comment: It says right in the title of the question, "What children's TV show..."

Comment: Yeah, I can no longer edit. I double-checked and you're right about the lack of weapons too. I think my memory conflated it with another. It's possible though to be mistaken about what is meant to be a children's show or not.

Answer (score 4):

My guess is *[Warriors of Kudlak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warriors_of_Kudlak)* from series 1 of *The Sarah Jane Adventures*.

It's about a laser-tag game where the children who are best at it disappear without a trace. And as it turns out, they are being recruited by

> aliens.

Answer (score 4):

While not *technically* a "computer game" in the strictest sense, this also reminds me of [Photon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon_%28TV_series%29), which was based on the laser-tag style game/set of toys.

Per Wikipedia:

> Photon followed the adventures of a young high school student, Christopher Jarvis with the alias of "Bhodi Li". Chris discovers that the lasertag game Photon is actually a way to detect the strongest warriors in the galaxy, who will then be recruited to fight the forces of darkness. After shooting his laser gun and saying "The light shines!", he would be transported to a space station to join his fellow Photon Warriors. His alien compatriots include an orphan earthling boy genius named Parcival, a shape-changing blob named Pike, a lizardoid named Leon, a cyborg named Lord Baethan, and Tivia, a black ninja princess from Nivia populated by women after the males became extinct. Their mentor is a sentient computer named MOM (Multiple Operation Matrix). The villains' motto is "Let the darkness grow!"

Answer (score 4):

[The Demon Headmaster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Demon_Headmaster_%28TV_series%29#Part_2_-_The_Prime_Minister.27s_Brain_.28Episodes_4-6.29) series (first broadcast on the BBC in 1996) featured a plot a little like this, although it was a girl, Dinah, who was good at the game.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're searching for Aaron Stone.
He also needs to fight mainly the villains that are included in the video game, and he also gets a Robot to live with him as a sort of handler/watcher.

http://www.tv.com/shows/aaron-stone/