# Twilight Zone TV show where boy is transported by toy

Tags: story-identification, the-twilight-zone

Looking for story where a father brings home toy and a boy plays with it until he is transported to another planet when he reaches top level.

Comment: Which Zone:  The Original?  1980's Series?  2000's Series?  Also are you sure it's not the Outer Limits or One Step Beyond or even maybe Night Gallery?

Comment: This question here shares much with [that question over there](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/41512/4495). Not sure if that's enough to call it a duplicate though. Neither the question nor the answers mentions Twilight Zone.

Comment: This story sounds a little bit like the short story "Mimsy were the borogoves" by Lewis Padgett - http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?189840 - where a young boy and his sister are transported away by toys they find. It was also made into a 2007 movie,  The Last Mimzy - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_Mimzy.

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like a story by S.C. Sykes. *The Cyphertone*. Boy receives a Simon like toy for Christmas. As he practices and gets better at the game his grades improve and the father notes the child is becoming "different". The boy tells him not to worry and that he goes "somewhere else" to learn new things. When the boy completes the top level of the game he is transported to an unknown place.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, if memory serves, it was an episode of an anthology series on A & E called "Short Stories" (or "Shortstories").    The episode was called "Somewhere Else".   I have a very crappy copy on VHS.

It starred Jon Devries, Justin Lerer, Nancy Weems and Crocker Nevin.

Screenplay by Mark Slater based on a story by S.C. Sykes

Directed by Mark Slater

Copyright is 1985 Production Concepts

Unfortunately, it's not listed on IMDB or anywhere that I've found on the internet.

Comment: Nice. Can you add some plot details to explain why this is it?

Comment: It would match with Bev's mention above of S.C. Sykes and "The Cyphertone".

Comment: Possibly this Short Stories? http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1685414/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1

Comment: Ah. And apparently not. From the producer, "The Short Stories that my old company Uden Associates produced for Channel 4 in the UK was an all-comers documentary series.  The A&E series was drama.  They were quite different and separate."

Comment: I ran across a Christian Science Monitor article that mentions A&E's Short Stories series, they apparently had a deal with the American Film Institute for it. Here is the relevant paragraph. ``And we are very interested in expanding our relationship with the new filmmakers of the world. We already have an arrangement with the American Film Institute for the `Short Stories' series. I would like to see us expand that to a larger number of young creative people from all over the country - not just New York and Los Angeles.'' https://www.csmonitor.com/1988/0727/lae.html Perhaps someone at the Inst

Comment: From a search: NORTH PENN
By NANCY KEENAN (A free-lance story for The Morning Call
The Morning Call
•
Oct 23, 1996 at 12:00 am
Science-fiction author Sony Sykes will co-host The Young Authors' Group's meeting 10:30 a.m.-noon Saturday at the Lansdale Public Library.
Oct 23, 1996 at 12:00 am
She will talk about science fiction writing and discuss some of her published works including her novel "Red Genesis," and her short story, "The Cyphertone," which was made into a movie titled "Somewhere Else." It was seen on Nickelodeon and the A&E; Channel and will be shown at the meeting.

Comment: The series on Nickelodeon was called "Special Delivery" and the episode "Somewhere Else" was broadcast on June 14, 1987.

Answer (score -6):

The bewitching pool...its on right now

Comment: The Bewitchin' Pool involves the children swimming to the bottom of a swimming pool and being transported. The father comes home and argues with the mother, resulting in their decision to get a divorce. There is no toy brought home, nor is there any insinuation that they are transported to another planet.

Comment: It would behoove you to explain why this fits the show in the question.

Comment: I'm not sure who flagged this as "low quality". The fact that it's wrong deserves a downvote, not a flag.

Comment: It may have been auto-flagged due to the short length. I'd also understand (though, not agree) if it was flagged for content for the lack of explanation as to why it matches.