# 1980s TV episode about a "Simon Says" Game leading to alien abduction

Tags: story-identification, aliens, tv

I've been trying to find this episode and remember seeing it vividly but have no idea what series it even was. Despite searching through different anthology series episode descriptions, I haven't found it.  Here's what I know:

- The tech was early 80s (Wargames era at best)
- The story involved a young boy becoming obsessed with a "Simon" (Memory) type of electronic game. He wanted to achieve an ultimate score I think.
- His dad is suspicious of the game and goes to investigate the toy maker.
- The designer of the game admits that he didn't really design it. The code/design was found on a satellite (or came as a message from space or something like this.  Not sure here but the basic point was that the game design was sent by aliens.
  *The dad rushes home only to barely see his son make the ultimate level and vanish before his eyes.
- Last shot is of the dad picking up the game and starting to play. It's the only way to get to his son.

Anyway - that's all I have. Like I said it was pretty vivid and it scared the crap out of me. I'd guess I saw it around 1987 or so.  I've searched everything I can on Google and nothing comes up so I'm starting to think I made it up!  Thanks for any tips!

Comment: Which country / language was it?

Comment: U.S./English is where I saw it.

Comment: Do you know if this was live action, animated, cartoon, or a mix?

Comment: I'm sure this was based on a short story.  I was thinking Bradbury, but I can't find evidence.  Despite the similar theme, it isn't "Mimsy Were The Borogoves".

Comment: Do you know if the prop used actually involved [the real Simon game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simon_(game))? Because I'm sure I've seen this in a sci-fi programme...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This particular show has been searched for quite a while on different sites. The closest match seems to be an episode of Nickelodeon's Special Delivery or A & E's Short Stories called *Somewhere Else*.This question  was previously asked [Twilight zone tv show where boy transported by toy.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/48631/twilight-zone-tv-show-where-boy-transported-by-toy/138329). The story was adapted from S.C Sykes' *The Cyphertone*;
`A boy receives a Simon like toy for Christmas. As he practices and gets better at the game his grades improve and the father notes the child is becoming "different". The boy tells him not to worry and that he goes "somewhere else" to learn new things. When the boy completes the top level of the game he is transported to an unknown place.' 
I also remember seeing it on tv, but couldn't place details of when or where.

Comment: Thanks! I'm sure that it. Just spent an hour searching for any trace of an archive of Shortstories and it looks like it has been overlooked thus far in transferring to the digital age. Appreciate your help.